# How can I validate an ECDSA signature using the signed data, signature and the signer ECDSA public key?

Tags: algorithm, openssl, digital-signature, ecdsa

In theory it should be possible to validate the signature of a piece of data if in possesion of the public key, signature and data that was signed and the hash algorithm is known.

I have all these components in binary format. Does anybody have an idea about the easiest way to validate this signature? OpenSSL? Python? An example would be great. Can it be done without writing code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it in Ruby.

```
require 'openssl'

signature = File.read('/path/to/sig.der')
data = File.read('/path/to/data')
pub_key = File.read('/path/to/ecdsa_pub_key')
key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(pub_key)
if key.dsa_verify_asn1(data, signature) == true
  puts 'verified'
end
```

This code requires that the OpenSSL linked against Ruby be compiled with elliptic curve support. (Red Hat flavored distributions of Linux do not satisfy this requirement)

If you're curious: dsa_verify_asn1 uses the [ECSDA_verify](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/ecdsa.html) function in the OpenSSL API.

Comment: I get "in `initialize': unknown curve name" using OpenSSL 1.0.1c on Ubuntu 12.10

Apparently it could do be done from the command line using openssl "dgst -hashfunction -verify public.key -signature file.sig file". I just don't understand how to convert the public EC key from hex to PEM format.

Comment: @DrewLex Try this to convert a binary key to pem: openssl ec -in key.der -inform DER -pubin -out keyout.pem -outform PEM

Answer (score 1):

You can use openssl to sign a message with a ECDSA signature, and then you can use openssl to verify the signature:

To sign a message (using SHA256 hashing, given the message and the signer's EC private key):

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign ec-privatekey.pem message.txt > signature.der
```

Then, to verify the signature (again using SHA256 hashing, given the message, the signer's EC public key, and the signature created above):

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify ec-publickey.pem -signature signature.der message.txt
```